# "Cook" vs "cook up" (when not referring to food)

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

Example sentence:

> Staring at her suspiciously, he asked, "What are you planning to cook up?

A native English speaker said I should add the "up," but another one said I shouldn't. So I'm a bit confused.

Note: I refer to anything that isn't food. For example, a plan.

Comment: Please add some context. Is it food, chemicals, or an idea/ excuse that are about to be prepared?

Comment: The sentence would more typically be, "What are you cooking up?".  Cooking up is planning, so your sentence would be like , "What are you planning to plan?"

Comment: @bukwyrm I stated in the question that it's anything that doesn't refer to food. So it's a plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both following definitions may fit in the context you provide,in any case, the idea is that of devising something:

to ***[cook up](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/cook-up)*** :

> - If someone cooks up a dishonest scheme, they plan it.
> - If someone cooks up an explanation or a story, they make it up.

(Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what is implied. "Cook up" refers to a scheming some mischief. In this case the "up" is required.

There are non-food things one can cook (no "up") but a heating process is implied, e.g. your car radiator.

Answer (score 1):

I know you specified a lack of food, but I need to give a complete explanation of the differences in order for it to all make sense.

Depending on usage, it may or may not be appropriate to add **up**. While it's *generally* true that **up** is used metaphorically and something without it is taken literally, that is not always the case.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [**cook up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cook%20up):

> **1** : to prepare (food) for eating especially quickly • I can *cook up* some hamburgers. • He *cooked* this whole meal *up* in less than 30 minutes.
>
> **2** : to invent (something, such as an idea, excuse, etc.) to deal with a particular situation • They *cooked up* a scheme to fool their neighbor. •    You'll have to *cook* an excuse *up* quickly.

Also, its definition of just [**cook**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cook#h2):

> **2** : to prepare for eating by a heating process
>   **3** : falsify, doctor
>
> - *cooked* the books with phony spending cuts and accounting gimmickry —Colleen O'Connor
>
> **4** : to subject to the action of heat or fire

---

In terms of the kitchen-based activity, there is a subtle distinction.

> I'm going to *cook* dinner.

This refers simply to the act of mixing, baking, or otherwise preparing the ingredients that make up dinner.

> I'm going to *cook up* dinner.

While it can mean the same thing, it's similar to saying, "I'm going to *whip up* dinner." It has a sense of quickness or triviality. It would be more common to hear, "Let me *just* cook *up* some dinner" than it would be to hear "Let me *just* cook dinner". (Unless a distinction is being made between eating in and going out or ordering in.)

---

Your example sentence, without further context, is ambiguous.

- If she is standing in front of him with a chef's apron and a mixing bowl, either **cook** or **cook up** would be appropriate.
- If she's holding a match in one hand and a non-food substance in the other, then it's likely just **cook** that should be used.
- If the context of the conversation is such that it seems she's concocting some plan (rather than there being anything to do with food or fire), than it's likely that **cook up** should be used. Barring, of course, the exception that she's considering falsifying a written record, in which case just **cook** could be used.

Given the possibilities, it's more likely (although not a given) that you do want to use **cook up**.